# Query for Closed Lost Oppurtunities

Tags: opportunity, query

Is there any way I could get a query pulled of Closed-Lost  opportunities, with  reason lost being “competitive advantage”?

Comment: Is there a field that specifies the reason on your opportunity record? Closed lost opportunities can  be selected by checking for StageName

Comment: Yes there is a field named reason on the opportunity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be like below,

```
SELECT Name FROM Opportunity
WHERE StageName = 'Closed-Lost'
AND Reason_Lost__c = 'Competitive Advantage'
```

Comment: Replace Reason_Lost__c with your reason field

Comment: It give me an error message. [object Object]: id, Name from Opportunity where Stage = 'Closed Lost' AND Reason_Lost__c ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:40 No such column 'Stage' on entity 'Opportunity'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: Sorry API name of stage field is stagename. Change stage = = 'Closed-Lost' to StageName = 'Closed-Lost'

Comment: Great..!..It worked